# How to change image size by dragging in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

How to change image size by dragging in ckeditor?

[image]

Please help me know what is addon of Ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/image2

"This is an enhanced version of the Image plugin that introduces the image widget. It includes the following features:

Integrated image captions.
An option to center images.
Dynamic "click and drag" resizing of images."